# How to add Splash Screen in Webview App? Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview, onesignal

I want to add splash screen to my webview app. I am not forced for editing webview and adding the push notifications but I cant add splash screen while url loading. I am working on this app.
[Github Code](https://github.com/jperla/OneSignal-WebView/blob/master/android/Examples/AndroidStudio/app/src/main/java/com/onesignal/example/MainActivity.java)
I know this a duplicated question but I cannot solve my problem.

Comment: In future, please include the well-formatted code as part of the question instead of a link. Also, you need to explain what you have tried and what malfunction you are experiencing.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla i'm not an english expert, sorry. i tried to copy here the code but it looks bad.. already, I want to add splash screen while url loading to my webview app.